# How to create a valid AuthenticationManager without a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I need access to a valid instance of a *AuthenticationManager* outside of a controller. For example, in a custom *AuthroizeAttribute*. In the template used to create an MVC 5 application that uses ASP.NET Identity it creates this code in the *AccountController* to create an instance of a *AuthenticationManager*.

```
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }
```

This *HttpContext* is a property of the Controller. How do I create an *AuthenticationManager* that has the correct context if I am not in a controller?

I am having a hard time finding any good documentation on ASP.NET Identity and OWIN.

Comment: Can't you get the current HttpContext with System.Web.HttpContext.Current?

Comment: That works. Thanks. If you want to put it in as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you get the current HttpContext with System.Web.HttpContext.Current? –